# Three.js MorphTargets

Tags: 3d, three.js

What the value represents when setting the morphTargetInfluences on a Mesh object.  I have been working with the WebGL Morph Targets example (see link below).  It seems to set a value between 0 and 1 and that changes the position of the vertices.  I am trying to figure out what the value actually represents.  If the cube has a size of 100 and I set the morph target influence to a value of 0.5 how do I determine what the height of that new cube is?

```
            bar.morphTargetInfluences[0] = value;
```

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_morphtargets.html

Answer (score 0):

The value is a scalar that determines the effect of a morph target. A morph target is another list of verticies (same length) that go along side the original list of verticies. Say we have a list of size 2 (a line),

```
var list1 = [0.1, -0.2]
```

and a morph target:

```
var list2 = [0.2, -0.3]
```

the scalar value is used like so:

```
finalVertexPosition = list1[0] + (list2[0] * scalar);
```

Its mainly used for animation (to transition from key to key).